# How can I get parent model object from signal in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I'm a beginner in python and django.
Can you explain to me, how can I get parent model from signal in onetomany relations.
For example, I have 2 models:

```
class ModelOne(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Modeltwo(models.Model):
 comment = models.CharField(max_length=20)
 mo = models.ForeignKey(ModelOne)
```

And signal for post_save:

```
@receiver(post_save)
def post_save_model(sender,instance,**kwargs):
 print("Signal: ",instance.objects.all().last())
```

How can I get related object of ModelOne in post_save_model function when I save ModelTwo?

Comment: Which model's save is handled in `post_save_model` method?

Comment: Any model. I don't determine explicitly. I want unified function for post_save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=ModelTwo)
def post_save_model(sender,instance,**kwargs):
     print("ModelOne: ", instance.mo)
```

Because `ModelOne` is a ForeignKey to `ModelTwo`, connected by field name `mo`. If you want to get all the ModelTwo instances connected to that `ModelOne` instance, then try like this:

```
@receiver(post_save)
def post_save_model(sender,instance,**kwargs):
    all_model_two_instances_queryset = instance.mo.modeltwo_set.all()
```

Comment: post_save_model finction is used for many models. How can I get foreign key "mo" and model_set modeltwo_set?

Comment: this does not make sense. You must define sender, here it is ModelTwo

Answer (score 0):

By prefetch, something like this:

```
Modeltwos.objects.prefetch_related('modelone_set')
```